# Can ideas "make a mark" on someone, or is this expression reserved for people?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I am writing about an idea that "stuck" with me, made an impression. The expression that came to mind is "it made a mark on me" but I see it used primarily referring to people making a mark on something or somebody.

The sentence: "This advice really made a mark in my thinking."

Thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: I can't speak for AmE, but in BrE it's *X made **its** mark on me*. And I've no doubt all native speakers would say ***on** my thinking,* not ***in***). I think it's just a matter of opinion whether you're happy for ***X*** to be something abstract, but I can't see anything wrong with saying an [***idea** made its mark on Y*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22idea+made+its+mark+on%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), even if ***Y*** is also abstract (as *the art of Rome*, in that link).

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(made+its+mark)%2C(left+its+mark)%2C(left+an+impression)%2C(made+an+impression)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28made%20its%20mark%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28left%20its%20mark%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28left%20an%20impression%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28made%20an%20impression%29%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful, and thanks for correcting the preposition, I was in doubt whether it was "on" or "in." And thank you Tim R. I am not sure how to acknowledge your responses to give you credit, but I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quote about explorers from *Englightenment Portraits* by Michel Vovelle:

Their curiosity-filled ambition and their confidence in the 
usefulness of knowledge made a mark on an epoch determined to combine commerce, science, and progress.

So not only can abstractions (here "ambition" and "confidence") make a figurative mark, but the mark need not be applied to a person, as here it is figuratively emblazoned on an epoch.